# Bootstrap Carousel Image does not scale proportionately

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

My carousel fills the width of the page, but when I scale down the window the y-axis does not respond.

Check it out [here](http://sacgamehub.com/index.html)

How can I maintain the original image proportions?

Answer (score 8):

Leave the explicit dimensions off all the images in the carousel and it should work properly.

Comment: @Eric Welcome to StackOverflow!  Users here are encouraged to upvote answers they find helpful and accept answers that solve their issues.  Find out more: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)