# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Not Stretching Background Images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like the carousel to scale proportionally the background image

in this question [Bootstrap Carousel Image does not scale proportionately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734195/bootstrap-carousel-image-does-not-scale-proportionately) it is suggested to leave the image explicit dimension but I can't understand what it means.

Comment: Hi @lowcoupling, I see you're working with Bootstrap's Carousel!  Friendly advice: for the best responses here try to ask questions that are [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Examples](http://sscce.org/).  Sometimes odd behavior only exists in your code so it can be hard to reproduce for strangers on the internet.  The best strategy is typically to post some code, and point out what's not working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set this in your **HTML**

For every `img` element in your carousel, you can set the `width` property to `100%` like this (although you shouldn't need to if the natural resolution is larger than the control):

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/OEdBxVD.jpg" width='100%'>
```

- normally, this image would be too small to expand fully, but 100% scales it up.
- make sure you don't have the `width` or `height` set to any pixel sizes

## [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/LzdUa/)

Since the image is going to go full screen, you should try to get your hands on a resolution that will naturally try to take up the full width available.  When the browser has to scale the image up, it will cause artifacts.

Comment: you should use css : .carousel .carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
}

Comment: and I use this to set a fixed height to the slider: .carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    height: 460px;
}

Answer (score 1):

What they mean is to leave off the width=px and height=px from the image (or image styles). You can set width="100%" and leave off the height. The browser will scale proportionally for you.

Comment: I'd have to see your code to really help. But try setting width="100%" directly in your img tags... so something like <img src="myimage.png" width=100%" />

Comment: thank you, I am trying but it doesn't seem to work. I am also trying <img src="myimage.png" style="width=100%">.

Comment: What image resolution should i use?

Answer (score 0):

Try this option without the inline styles. Just add this to your stylesheet to override the bootstrap.css style.

```
.carousel .item {
width: 100%;
/*slider width*/
max-height: 600px;
/*slider height*/
}
.carousel .item img {
width: 100%;
/*image width*/
}
```